# How to get exact .css target from chrome dev tools?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, google-chrome-devtools

I use Chrome Dev Tools to explore the sizing of elements on my webpage.  We're using a pdf viewer plugin from [Krajee](https://plugins.krajee.com/) and I'd like to force the element size to 500x500 px.  I can find the element in chrometools and adjust the style there manually as show below.

[image]

I'd now like to update `app.css` to always make this 500x500px.  As you can see, the element is quite nested (ie. `file-preview-frame -> kv-file-content -> kv-preview-data`).  So I have no clue how to target this for .css.  **Is there a way to get the .css path of this element from chrome tools?**  In other words, can I copy paste something from chrometools into my .css file that will correctly set this element (or this element class)?

PS: I'm guessing it's something like `myviewer.file-preview-frame.kv-file-content.kv-preview-data` but is there a way to just copy this and not have to guess a million possibilities?  Sorry I am not great at css.

### Update

Based on comments/answers the recommendation is to right click and copy selector.  In doing so I get the following:

```
#preview-1600093158823_90-0 > div.kv-file-content > embed
```

So two problems here.  First, the id (16000...) changes on each page load.  I guess the plugin hasn't ID'd this embed properly.  Second, can this copied selector be dropped directly into the `app.css` file?  IE is it valid .css or is it only valid jQuery and I'd have to access it from javascript/jQuery?

### How to Reproduce

Go to [Krajee demo](https://plugins.krajee.com/file-preview-management-demo), choose the element corresponding to the acrobat.pdf file in the first demo and choose the embed.

[image]

Comment: In Dev Tools: Right click the element, Copy > Copy Selector

Comment: @ajmnz can you see my updated answer

Comment: It can be used in your css file, but as the answer below says, chances are you won't need the full selector. Given that the ID changed on page load, does `div.kv-file-content > embed` work?

Comment: No that doesn't chagne anything.  But do I have to reference the library it came from?  For example `.krajee-default.file-preview-frame.kv-file-content`?

Comment: Are you trying to modify an element from an iframe by any chance? Could you please share a website link or Jsfiddle?

Comment: Yes - I updated answer on how to reproduce.  Sorry, required plugin so can't use jsfiddle right?  Yes I think it's an iframe (am noob - what complications does that add?).  Also feel free to leave your suggestions from comments as an answer so I can upvote and give you rep for helping me

Answer (score 2):

You can right click the element in Dev tools, and copy the css selector.

[image]

You can then paste that directly into your css file, and put styles in after curly braces.

Chances are you don't need the full selector as this gives you though, sometimes just an id is enough. Also often (especially with css-in-js), the classnames given to the elements are not consistent, but change between page renders.

---

#### Update

If the css target from the dev tools isn't good enough, (as in the specific website given in the updated question), then you can use data attributes to select the element, so:

```
div[data-template="pdf"] > div.kv-file-content > embed
```

Comment: Can you see me updated answer and recommend further?  Thanks for this

Comment: Your update doesn't really have much to do with the original question, as you need to write a manual selector if the one given by chrome tools isn't good enough for your needs.